# Generating CSRF token on frontend in my React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, csrf, cryptojs

I created an application with Node js as backend and React js on frontend . My react app is running on localhost:3000 and my node js server is running on localhost:3005 .

I also implemented CORS policy in my node js app , only allowing origin localhost:3000 ( my react app ) for sending request to my backend node js server . In this case CORS will not allow any request from any other app running on different origin . Is that true this will somewhat protect my app from CSRF attack .

In addition to this , i will generate a token from a secret on frontend and with every request from frontend to backend i will send this token as a custom header to make sure that this request is only coming from my frontend app ( this secret will only known to my front react app and backend server ) . When this request goes to backend , in backend i will verify that token and checks that this token is created by same secret which i used in frontend .

Is this a good technique to mitigate CSRF or something i am missing here . I am a beginner trying to understand how things work . Please guide my if you have any suggestion .

Comment: You can't generate CSRF from the front-end. Anyone can generate it and send the request. CSRF must be generated from the server.

Comment: I will generate token with a secret and that secret is not known to any other person .  Then i will send that token to backend and there i will verify that token with the help of secret if it gets verified it means that token is correct . In case of other people , then don't know the secret which i used to generate the token , hence if they generate the token obviously with different secret there token will not be verified . This will act similar to JWT token .